# Import XML file to excel with existing map using ExcelPackage in C#

Tags: c#, xml, excel, dictionary

How can I import xml file to existing excel template. I have a map (xsd).

It has to be done on server. I used excelPackage , but couldnt find any documentation for the classes.

More specific question: how do I write in C# the following code from VB.NET

```
Dim xmlSchema As String = "c:\Schema1.xsd" 
Map = XL.ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add(xmlSchema) 
Wb.XmlImportXml(xmlStr, oMap)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is extensive documentation and tutorials and everything on the Codeplex site for ExcelPackage:

http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/

As for your question:

- if you have a XSD file, you can easily deserialize your XML file into an object graph
- parse the objects as needed and insert the relevant information into a new Excel sheet based on your template

Your question is way too broad and not specific enough to be able to help with it - you'll need to make your question more specific and provide more information!

Comment: more specific question: how do I write in C# the following code from vb: 
        Dim xmlSchema As String = "c:\Schema1.xsd"
Map = XL.ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add(xmlSchema)
Wb.XmlImportXml(xmlStr, oMap)